# How to create a list of the most recent 45 image frames of a kinect

Tags: c#, arrays, kinect, assign

Im trying to store the most recent 45 color frames from a kinect. My idea was that I could take the colorPixel array used by the kinect to store the pixel data in byte form, and save that into a jagged array I called Frames. The code below is what the event handler of a standard color viewer for the kinect would look like `

```
//These are global parameter
next index = 0;
byte[45][] Frames;
byte nextIndex = 0; 

//This is the event handler within the code for a typical color viewer  
void sensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Opens the color frame sent from the event handler and declares it
        //as 'colorFrame'.
        using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            /*Check to see if colorFrame is null. It will be null if this frame cannot
            be processed before the event handler registers another frame. This
            results in the null frame being dropped as there is no method for 
            colorFrame == null.*/
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {            
                //Copies a frame of data to 'colorPixels'.
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorPixels);

                //Assigns colorPixels to the array Frames. Also, this will only store
                //the 45 most recent Frames
                Frames[nextIndex] = colorPixels;              
                nextIndex++;
                if (nextIndex == 45)
                {
                    nextIndex = 0;
                }               
                /*Updates the pixels in the specified region of the bitmap. Parameteres:
                Int32Rect- Describes the width, height, and location of an integer rectangle
                   XAML value for X coordinate of top left corner
                   XAML value for Y coordinate of top left corner
                   Width of the rectangle
                   Heigth of the rectangle
                Pixels- the pixel array used to update the bitmap
                Stride- the stride of the update region in pixels
                Offset- the input buffer offset */
                colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                   new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorBitmap.PixelWidth, colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                   colorPixels,
                   colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                   0);
             }
        }
    }`
```

The issue with that code is that when it is run, it assigns the current array being processed (colorPixels) to every element of the Frames array. So the first array colorPixels from the first frame is stored as Frames[0], however when the event handler fires again and the second array of colorPixels is ready, Frames[0] and Frames[1] both are reassigned as the colorPixel array for frame 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have only one byte buffer and assign a reference to that single byte buffer to several array elements.

I would recommend to use a list of byte buffers instead of a multi-dimensional array. That would be easier to read.

**First**: Remove the definition of your byte buffer `colorPixels` and replace it with

```
const int frameCount = 45;    
List<byte[]> frames;
```

**Second**: You have to initialize your buffers. Somewhere in your code you initialize your byte buffer with somthing like

```
this.colorPixels = new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];
```

Initialize your byte buffers instead with something like:

```
frames = new List<byte[]>(frameCount);
for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
{
   frames.Add(new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength]);
}
```

**Third**: Use the buffers in your eventhandler.

```
byte[] colorPixels = frames[nextIndex];
if (++nextIndex >= frameCount)
{
   nextIndex = 0;
}

colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorPixels);
colorBitmap.WritePixels(...
```

Comment: Note you can use `List`s with defined capacities